# How do I parse this into a MultiValued Map?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I have a string that is
`name,5486984,189.658.235.215,3.158.68.15,name2,189189,189.658.218.268,3.158.68.13...`

and so on

I was thinking that I would put this into a map but I'm not entirely sure. I'm looking at the Apache Commons Collection library that has Multivalued map. Even if I use that I am unsure how to parse this StringArray into it.

EDIT:

Thank you for the response. My overall goal is getting that String to show up in a JSF Drop down.
I have

```
<f:selectItems itemValue="#{mainBean.information}" value="#mainBean.information}" />
```

in my Java I have

```
Private String [] information;
information = config.getStringArray("information"); // This brings in this string from the property file
```

I've been referencing this
http://www.horstmann.com/corejsf/refcard.html

So with what I have here, that I just posted. It will populate every element of that string array. I only want the "name" to show up and the three other values to be passed as the actual "value".

I may need to make a new question I guess.

I tried to make a Map object that is a string and a string array but JSF refuses to take it.

Here is the new question:
[JSF I need to populate selectItems with a StringArray but I need to parse it first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918956/jsf-i-need-to-populate-selectitems-with-a-stringarray-but-i-need-to-parse-it-fir)

Comment: What the structure of that data e.g. what's the key ? Which are your values ?

Comment: It is currently in a String[]. I am pulling it out of a properties file. I am using JSF to do "SelectItems" but I don't want every element shown. I just want each name to be the key and the following three values after the name to be the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Apache Commons for the multimap, and you know there are four values:

```
MultiMap map = new MultiHashMap();    
String[] elements = source.split(",");

// process the elements in groups of four
for (int keyIndex = 0; keyIndex < elements.length; keyIndex += 4) {
  String key = elements[keyIndex];
  map.put(key, elements[keyIndex+1]);
  map.put(key, elements[keyIndex+2]);
  map.put(key, elements[keyIndex+3]);
}
```

In the end you get a `MultiMap` with three elements per key. You should of course do some sanity checks on the data, but the basic idea is above.

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from your question,
Try this ::

Let your data be :

```
   String data = "name,5486984,189.658.235.215,3.158.68.15,name2,189189,189.658.218.268,3.158.68.13"

// Now you have 

    String[] sections = data.split(",");
```

The sections will have data like :

sections[0] = "name,5486984,189.658.235.215,3.158.68.15";
sections[1] =  "name2,189189,189.658.218.268,3.158.68.13";

Comment: split by ",", your sections[0] should be "name" right? or I missed something?

Comment: Unless your `split()` is psychic, it will not know to split only on every fourth comma ;).

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need a mutivalued/multimap.

a `map <String, String[]>` is enough i think.

well still with the **split** idea

```
@Test
public void testIt() {
    final String s = "name,5486984,189.658.235.215,3.158.68.15," +
            "name2,189189,189.658.218.268,3.158.68.13," +
             "name3,5486984,189.658.235.215,3.158.68.15," +
             "name4,189189,189.658.218.268,3.158.68.13";
    final String[] sections = s.split(",(?=[a-zA-Z])");
    final Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    String[] tmp;
    for (final String sec : sections) {
        tmp = sec.split(",", 2);
        map.put(tmp[0], tmp[1].split(","));
    }
    //just for output
    for (final String k : map.keySet()) {
        LOG.debug("{} - {}", k, Arrays.toString(map.get(k)));
    }
}
```

output:

```
DEBUG: name3 - [5486984, 189.658.235.215, 3.158.68.15]
DEBUG: name4 - [189189, 189.658.218.268, 3.158.68.13]
DEBUG: name - [5486984, 189.658.235.215, 3.158.68.15]
DEBUG: name2 - [189189, 189.658.218.268, 3.158.68.13]
```

if you really need a collection/List as value, `Arrays.asList(array)` could help you.